# Error E0433 - Use of undeclared type or module when accessing a module from a test

Tags: rust

As a first project in Rust, I'm trying to create a run length encoding library.

This is my `src/lib.rs` (initially created by cargo):

```
#[cfg(test)]

mod rle;
mod tests {

    #[test]

    fn it_works() {
        let rle1 = rle::Rle {
            lengths: vec![1, 4, 2],
            values: vec![1, 2, 1],
        };
    }

}
```

This is my `src/rle.rs`:

```
pub struct Rle {
    lengths: Vec<i32>,
    values: Vec<i32>,
}
```

Using this layout, I get an `error[E0433]: failed to resolve. Use of undeclared type or module 'rle'`

I have tried to follow the guidelines in the Rust Docs called [Crates and Modules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/crates-and-modules.html).

What am I doing wrong?

In case the layout was not obvious:

```
$ ls src
lib.rs rle.rs
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have an error in the use of `#[cfg(test)]`.

Rust has two ways of applying attributes:

- `#[...]` applies to the next item
- `#![...]` applies to the enclosing item

This means that here, `#[cfg(test)]` is applying to the next item (`mod rle;`) which will thus only be compiled in test mode. On the other hand, your `tests` module will always be compiled.

As a result, when NOT running in test mode, you have:

- no `rle` module
- a `tests` module referring to a `rle` module

The fix is simple: move the attribute so it applies to `mod tests`, not `mod rle`.

---

Note:

- as mentioned by Chris, you ALSO need to use `super::rle` to refer to the `rle` module.
- as mentioned by ljedrz, you ALSO need to declare the fields of `Rle` public to be able to name them from outside the file (a problem you should not have if the tests are in the same file).

Comment: @Shepmaster: Ah right. I usually put the tests in the same file, which bypasses this `pub` thing :) I do think though that once the `rle` module is located the rest should be more explicit. I wonder if the compiler could give hints as to how bringing `rle` into scope as the message for now is cryptic and does not hint at a solution at all.

Comment: Yeah, the organization shown in the OP is a bit... non-traditional ^_^. That's why we are here though, to learn better ways!

Answer (score 5):

You first need to make `Rle` fields public to be able to access them:

```
pub struct Rle {
    pub lengths: Vec<i32>,
    pub values: Vec<i32>,
}
```

And then, in the `lib.rs` file you should use it like so:

```
mod rle; // you probably don't want #[cfg(test)] to apply to rle

#[cfg(test)] // this makes the tests module run only during cargo test
mod tests {
    use super::rle::Rle; // now Rle is applicable in the tests module

    #[test]
    fn it_works() {
        let rle1 = Rle {
            lengths: vec![1, 4, 2],
            values: vec![1, 2, 1],
        };
    }

}
```

Note that I changed `let rle1 = rle::Rle {` to `let rle1 = Rle {`, because I imported `super::rle::Rle` and not just `super::rle`.

This compiles without issues.

Comment: Why would anyone need `#![cfg(test)]` at top level of the crate?

Comment: If they only wanted to run a test, like in this case :). But you're right, it's somewhat exotic. I'll amend my answer.